# Running executable script from iCloud folder

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm running an executable script from my iCloud folder. I get the following error

"ERROR: run_shell_command on /Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs... /bin/bash: /Users/username/Library/Mobile: No such file or directory"

which has to do with the space between "Mobile" and "Documents" in the iCloud path. How do you handle these cases. I'm sure there is an easy solution but I can't figure it out.

I've checked running the script in my local machine and it works. However, I would prefer to do this from the cloud to optimize space.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow! Please indent the code line for readability. Use the help button inside editor.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are escaped with the \ character.

For example:

```
cd /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents
```

You can also enclose the argument in quotes:

```
cd '/Users/username/Library/Mobile Documents'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves the space-in-path problem on iCloud Drive *persistently*:

```
# bash 5 will expand $HOME to your home dir path.
# Or, replace '$HOME' with /Users/<username>

cd ~
ln -s "$HOME/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" icloud
cd ~/icloud
```

From `~/icloud` I enjoy command line access. My bash autocomplete works. I can ignore the tildes and space. I use unix naming for the files and directories below `~/icloud`, to make script access easier.

@cmartinezvil if you get tired of quoting paths every time, the `symlink` is handy. You can get the docs using `info ln` on MacOs.

Thanks go to [@jl-peyret](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/116013/jl-peyret) for this answer.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428604/how-to-make-icloud-drive-conveniently-available-to-the-shell/448685#448685